# Can't get Macros/VBA to run on other computers - ms-word

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office, settings

Having some immense issues with allowing a form I've put together that needs to be distributed to everyone in our office, the only issue is; it won't run properly on other computers. The VBA source I'm using can be seen below:

```
Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal ContentControl As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)

    If ContentControl.Title = "checkbox4" Then

        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("AP2").Range.Font.Hidden = ContentControl.Checked

    End If

    If ContentControl.Title = "checkbox5" Then

        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Bookmark").Range.Font.Hidden = ContentControl.Checked

        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("AP1").Range.Font.Hidden = ContentControl.Checked

    End If

    If ContentControl.Title = "checkbox1" Then

        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("approve").Range.Font.Hidden = ContentControl.Checked

    End If


    If ContentControl.Title = "checkbox2" Then

        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("sign1").Range.Font.Hidden = ContentControl.Checked

        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("sign2").Range.Font.Hidden = ContentControl.Checked

    End If


    If ContentControl.Title = "checkbox3" Then

        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("note").Range.Font.Hidden = ContentControl.Checked

    End If

End Sub
```

On Mac's; opening the document prompts for macros to be enabled, and when doing so, it runs perfectly fine. On all other desktops/laptops, they are either prompted or not, but regardless, none of the actual VBA code works, and I've gone through settings enabling macros/vba and none of them seem to help.

Any suggestions are really appreciated!

Comment: Do you get an error when running the Sub? You tested on multiple Mac's I'm assuming? PS: Globally enabling Macro's for a PC is not secure from what I have read.

Comment: No error at all shows, simply; nothing happens. I've tried on the few Mac's we have in the office, and they all seem to handle it perfectly fine, I'm just completely lost as to why it's having difficulties on some Window's desktops.

Comment: Which version of Word/Office is installed on these machines? Have you made sure the document is saved in a ***trusted location***? (Look in the Trust Center, where you also found the option to enable macros to run.)

Comment: Using Office 2013 on all Computers in the office, and yes the file is in a trusted location.